# Maximum limit of characters into rich text box

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, field-controls

I am using Sharepoint rich text box control. I would like to know what is the maximum limit of characters that can be entered into rich text box.

I am using the sharepoint rich text box control to enter mesaage and send mail to perticular user.

Also I wanted to know if there will be any kind of style issues in mail box after applying colors to text in mailbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Document libraries and lists have different options available w.r.t to the multiple lines of text column type. In document libraries, when you create a new column of type Multiple Lines of Text, you get the option to select the ‘Allow unlimited length in document libraries’ checkbox.

But, In lists, this option does not exist.

A multi line text field is defined in sharepoint as a 'Note' type, this is stored in the the DB as a ntext sql type.In the SQL type can store 2gb of char data, that's 1,073,741,823 characters.

Also, it is not advisavle to store such huge data in sharepoint column as it may hamper performance.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointgeneral/thread/5e8cc504-03d0-4d26-81f9-1608c2c5881f)